# how to express an idea based on belief?

Tags: grammaticality, expression-choice

Many people around the globe elevate the value of travelling abroad between several countries upon a belief that such activities could expand their horizons.

My question particularly is about how to express an idea based on belief which refers to a specific conclusion?

In another word: 
Many people around the globe already believe that travelling abroad could expand their horizons. As a result, they elevate the value of travelling abroad between several countries.

Am I correct or should its formulation change? 
If there are any other ways to express about thoughts please share it

Comment: They *elevate the value of travelling abroad **in the belief that** such activities could expand their horizons.* Note - that particular construction often implies that the author/speaker *doesn't share that belief*.

Comment: adding your own research to this ? would increase its value and validity.

Comment: Are 'ideas' based on 'belief' or does belief generate ideas ?

Comment: First please not that “Many people around the globe elevate the value of traveling abroad between several countries upon a belief that such activities could expand their horizons” is comprehensible despite, not because of the grammar or syntax or vocabulary. In strict examination, it would fall at several posts.

What research did you do, and what conclusion would it have supported if you’d posted it, please?

Comment: @Nigel J   I changed the way of illustration to be more clarified

Comment: @Robbie Goodwin   I changed the way of illustration to be more clarified

Comment: so ... you want something like 'changing geolocation is propitious t X'?

Comment: It might be more appropriate to express such a belief in the value of travel as an *assumption*.

Comment: Mohamed, please first recognise that if there's any extend to which ideas are not based on beliefs, that pretty-much balances the extent to which beliefs are not based on ideas. In all seriousness, no question about how to express an idea based on belief which refers to a specific conclusion could matter, unless you could first explain how or why, if not both…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Thinking**, according to *Oxford Living Dictionaries*:

> *"A person's ideas or opinions."*[1](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/thinking),  or
>
> *"The process of considering or reasoning about something."* [1](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/thinking)

Some example sentences:

> "‘The observation that stimulated my **thinking** on this topic was of a humble grammatical phenomenon.’"[1](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/thinking)
>
> "‘It is my sincere hope that our readers will find many new perspectives and ideas to challenge their **thinking**.’"[1](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/thinking)
>
> "‘But does this line of **thinking** mean that we should all live in cities?’"[1](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/thinking)
>
> "‘Make voting more accessible, the **thinking** goes, and more citizens will vote.’" [1](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/thinking)

In your sentence:

> *Many people around the globe elevate the value of travelling abroad between several countries **thinking** that such activities could expand their horizons.*